# unable to connect to sql server database from windows application c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I am creating a simple windows c# application for internal reports, i am unable to connect to sql server

Below is the code in App.config code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="krConnectionstring" connectionString= "DataSource = 128.129.40.225;Initial Catalog=PRPO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=intranet;Password=Authorise"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
  </configuration>
```

In the Form the code as below

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string connstr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["krConnectionstring"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr);
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

I am getting error as

An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.

Thanks

Comment: There isn't any **Provider** added in the `connectionString` plus its not a valid datasource.. Check it once again..

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `DataSource`, replace it by `Data Source` with space.

Try this..

```
<add name="krConnectionstring" connectionString="Data Source=128.129.40.225;Initial Catalog=PRPO;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=intranet;Password=Authorise "
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Thank You, Its because of DataSource, with out having space in between the words.I got it:)

Comment: @Kumar , you're welcome .. kindly mark as answer :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Its because of DataSource not having space in connection string,i added the space in between the words and it worked perfectly.